# A question about performatives

Tags: tense, sentence-structure

> Some verbs used as performatives with the present simple in affirmative sentences have a similar meaning with either the present simple or the present continuous in negative sentences. [Source](https://www.bebc.co.uk/lookinside/9781107697386.pdf)

What is the meaning that some verbs used as performatives is similar in a positive sentence to a negative sentence in the present simple？

Comment: Where did you find that line? The one you quoted. Please provide reference link or citation.

Comment: There's nothing "interesting" about the fragment you've cited, which simply makes the point that there's no real difference between the two "performatives" ***I promise** to marry you* and ***I am promising** to marry you*. I think that's an inconsequential observation, which is only being made at all because the immediately preceding text describes a clear difference in emphasis between ***I regret** marrying you* and ***I am / I'm regretting** marrying you*.

Comment: (That "difference in emphasis" only arises because the "performative" utterances *must* be happening *at time of speaking*, so it's semantically irrelevant whether we reflect that in the choice of verb form with ***promise***. But with ***regret***, it can make a big difference - all the way from regretting something almost as soon as you did it - possibly some time ago - to only starting to feel regret at time of speaking, or immediately before you opened your mouth.)

Answer (score 0):

The referenced material compares these two nagative sentences

Simple present:

> I don’t deny taking the books, but Miguel said it would be okay.

Present continuous

> I'm not denying taking the books, but Miguel said it would be okay.

they mean pretty much the same thing. In contrast the affirmative equivalents have slightly different feeling.

Simple present

> I deny taking the books.

Present continuous

> I am denying taking the books.

Personally, I am not sure this has a different meaning, but is does have a rather different feeling. I agree with FumbleFingers comment that native English speakers would rarely use this formulation.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why a native speaker would use the progressive verb form when denying something, except as a (facetious?) response to someone asking *What are you doing/saying?* That's to say, it would probably "feel different" because you'd be left thinking *Why did he say it like that?*

Comment: I think there's more of a difference with "I regret" and "I'm regretting". The former describes a permanent state, while "I'm regretting" would be temporary or jocular: "I regret telling you that" (I'm genuinely sorry I told you) vs "I'm regretting telling you that" (Oops, now you're teasing me about it, that's momentarily embarrassing).